# Isomorphism of quotients implies isomorphism of the denominator

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

> Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $I \subset J$ two ideals of $A$.
> Let's suppose we have $A/I \simeq A/J$ as $A$-modules. Using the second isomorphism theorem can we deduce that $I \simeq J$ ?

I think it is true but i would like to check it (or find a counterexample).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important to clarify whether you are requiring $A/I\simeq A/J$ as $A$-modules, or as just abelian groups.

If you are considering isomorphism as abelian groups, then Angry_Math_Person provides a counter-example.

However, $A/I\simeq A/J$ as $A$-modules implies $I=J$. Indeed, suppose $I\subset J$ and $\varphi\colon A/I\to A/J$ is an $A$-module isomorphism. For any $x\in J$, we have $\varphi(x)=x\varphi(1)=0\in A/J$ so since $\varphi$ is injective, we have $J=I$.

Answer (score 1):

What about $A$ = infinite product of $\mathbb Z$.
$I= \mathbb Z$ and $J = \mathbb Z ^2$?

Comment: Okay yes, then my answer was probably specific of my problem where i was working with $\mathbb{K}[x_1,..,x_n]$, $J=ker(\phi)$ for some  $\phi : \mathbb{K}[x_1,..,x_n] \to \mathbb{K}[t]$  and $I=(f_1,f_2)$.

Comment: $A/I$ and $A/J$ are not isomorphic as $A$-modules?

Comment: @KentaS, aren't they, though? I don't see the problem here.

Comment: $A/I$ and $A/J$ are both isomorphic to $A$ itself.

Comment: @Angry_Math_Person They cannot possibly be isomorphic as $A$-modules. Let $\psi\colon A\to A/I$ be an $A$-module isomorphism. Then for any $x\in I$ we have $\psi(x)=x\psi(1)=0\in A/I$, so $\psi$ is not injective.